# Changing currency in Latex that's not Dollar, Pound or Euro

Tags: latex, xelatex

How do I change a currency in a Latex template? Something that's text based, like South African Rand (symbol > 'R'). Latex doesn't recognize ZAR etc.

FYI: I'm currently using an invoice template.

Comment: write a question, and write an answer. Accept that answer. Remove [SOLVED] from the title. Stackoverflow is not a forum.

Comment: Is this okay now? Thanks for the help guys. I'll accept my answer in two days (as required).

Comment: Yeah, this looks fine. This question might be migrated to tex.stackexchange.com, but don't worry, it's nothing you have to worry about. Have an upvote!

Comment: Cross-network duplicate: [Invoice class: how to change currency](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253012/5764)

Comment: @Werner, the problem is that other currencies aren't taken into account by the dollar -> pound change, as those are symbol based. This is how one would change the currency to a text based "symbol".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within invoices, or any template containing a currency you'll want to change, simply write the next:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{dapper-invoice}

\renewcommand{\$}{\text{R}}
```

In the above instance, I'm changing $ to ZAR (South African Rand). It's a simple way of changing the currency to a text-like currency (eg. 'R').